# Angular google maps HeatmapLayer undefined

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am trying to create a heat map but on running the app it does show me a map but the heatLayer doesn't show up and in the console i get an error message saying heatmapLayer undefined. On further investigating the issue i see that on `console.log(google.map)` it gives me different objects but `visualizing` object does not exist in it. I have followed [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agm-healtmap?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) stackblitz. Here is the code

Html

```
<div class="fuse-card auto-width p-16">
    <div #gmap class="map-heat-container" style="height: 500px; width: 500px"></div>
</div>
```

Component

```
 map: google.maps.Map;
 heatmap: google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer;   
ngOnInit() {
this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, {
              zoom: 3.5,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.5204, 74.3587),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
              zoomControl: false,
              streetViewControl: false,
              disableDefaultUI: true,
            });
            console.log(google.maps.visualization);
            this.heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
              data: this.getPoints(),
              map: this.map,
            });
  } 

  getPoints() {
    // create points
    let markers: Marker[] = [
      { lat: -23, lng: -46 },
      { lat: -24, lng: -53 },
      { lat: -23, lng: -46 },
    ];

    // transforming points
    return markers.map((point) => new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng));
  }
```

I have added `libraries: ["visualization"]` with my google apiKey in module but still it doesn't work

```
 AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: "myApiKey",
      libraries: ["visualization"],
    }),
```

Comment: is the visualization library removed from google core module? if not then is there any mistake i am making or is there any other way to get visualization to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with maps cdn inside index.html file. The cdn contains libraries of geometry and places but not of visualization. So i updated that cdn and ran the app again and it worked. But the visualization library should be first one and imported before geometry and places for it to take effect.

```
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxw&libraries=visualization&geometry&places&language=en">
</script>
```

Comment: Remove your API Key especially if it is unrestricted, otherwise, you may be subject to abuse and misuse. Publicly exposing your credentials can result in unintended use, which could lead to unexpected charges on your account. I would recommend that you take a look at the [API Key best practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#api_key_table) to learn more on how you can protect your API Key(s).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out I really did made a big mistake here